# Xamarin Forms app fails to deploy in Windows Phone with "System.TypeLoadException"

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin Forms app runs successfully in Android but fails to run in Windows Phone 8.1. It shows -
`An exception of type "'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in MyAppName.DLL but was not handled in user code"` in the InitializeComponent() method .

Note: This is a Prism MVVM App and the 'App' class inherits from 'PrismApplication'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the real reason, but there was a Page named `MainPage.xaml` both in my PCL project and WindowsPhone 8.1 project. I was using the page in PCL project and after renaming it, the app worked :)